# Is modifying an object through a pointer to const undefined behavior?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Suppose we have an `int` variable referenced as `const int*`which in turn is aliased as `int *`. Is it clear from the Standard if modifying the variable through the `int *` pointer is undefined behavior or not?

As an illustration, consider the following code:

```
void increment(int* p) {
    (*p)++;
}

void call_increment(const int* p) {
    increment(p);
}

int main(void) {
    int x = 7;
    int* p = &x;

    call_increment(p);
}
```

Comment: The code you show is ill-formed, the qualification conversion is invalid

Comment: GCC with defaults: `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘increment’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type`

Answer (score 8):

Modifying an object through a pointer to `const` is ill-formed, not undefined behavior.
Fixing that by casting away the `const` is well-formed unless the object referred to is actually `const`.

Your code has a different problem:
You are discarding a `const`-qualifier when passing `p` from `call_increment()` to `increment()`.

Any useful compiler will complain about that [even without being prompted](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b7657c7230e7eba):

```
g++ -x c -std=c18 main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In function 'call_increment':
main.cpp:6:15: warning: passing argument 1 of 'increment' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
     increment(p);
               ^
main.cpp:1:21: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'const int *'
 void increment(int* p) {
                ~~~~~^
```

Just heed it, and better ask for more with at least `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Yes. But any cast hints at a potential error, as it overrides the (minimal) guard-rails, so should be avoided by refarctoring if feasible.

Comment: You should mention that conversion of the `const int *` back to an `int *` is valid and results in a pointer to the original object due to C 2018 6.3.2.3 7: “A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil `int` is not a different object type compared to `int`. It is the same type, so 6.3.2.3/7 does not apply.

Comment: @Lundin: `const int` and `int` are different types.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If they are, why does 6.3.2.3/2 exist. If it was already covered by  6.3.2.3/7 then it is superfluous.

Comment: @Lundin: Paragraph 2 says you can add qualifiers. Paragraph 7 says you can go back to the original. Paragraph 7 is not superfluous because it allows you to remove qualifiers that were not originally present (but not qualifiers that were originally part of an object definition) by returning to an earlier type, which paragraph 2 does not cover because it is only about adding qualifiers.

Answer (score 2):

The `const` qualifier in C specifies that an lvalue will not be used to modify an object, but generally says nothing about whether the object might be modified in other ways, including through non-const-qualified pointer derived from the lvalue in question.

Two notable cases where it does have implications about the object:

1. If a top-level lvalue is declared `const` but not `volatile`, there would be no defined means by which its value can change, and the Standard would invite implementations to freely assume that it won't.  If a top-level lvalue is `const volatile`, the Standard would not anticipate any particular means via which the value could change, but quality implementations should generally allow for the possibility that the value might be spontaneously changed by means they know nothing about.
2. If a pointer to a `const` object is qualified `restrict`, any object observed via that pointer or any lvalue derived from an address stored therein must have the same value throughout the active lifetime of the pointer.  Thus, given e.g.

   ```
   int test(int const *restrict p)
   {
     if (*p == 1)
     {
       doSomething(p);
       return *p;
     }
     else
       return 1;
   }
   ```

   a compiler would be allowed to generate code that returns 1 without reloading `*p`, but it would not be allowed to do so without the `restrict` qualifier.  This would also be true of e.g.

   ```
   int test(int const *p)
   {
     int const * restrict pp = p;
     if (*pp == 1) // Restrict-qualified pointer used to observe value
     {
       doSomething(pp);
       return *pp;
     }
     else
       return 1;
   }
   ```

   but not

   ```
   int test(int const *p)
   {
     int const * restrict pp = p;
     if (*p == 1)
     {
       doSomething(pp);
       return *p;
     }
     else
       return 1;
   }
   ```

   If a copy of `p` had been previously stored in a global object and `doSomething` were to completely ignore `pp`, changes to `*p` would not affect any object accessed via pointer derived from `pp`.

If one wants to maximize optimizations by indicating that an object identified via pointer will never change, one should generally qualify the pointer as `restrict` in addition to identifying the object as `const`.